# сообщение на почту python

Tags: python

нужно сделать код,который будет запрашивать имя пользователя и почту,а затем на почту пользователя отсылать сообщение 'привет,имя пользователь' с темой'тест'
код:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
name=input('введите ваше имя')
server='smtp.yandex.ru'
sms_from='mail@yandex.ru'
password='password'
sms_to=input('введите вашу почту:')

sender='mail@yandex.ru'
subject='тест'
text=('здравствуйте,',name)

msg=MIMEMultipart()
msg['From']=sms_from
msg['To']=sms_to
msg['subject']=subject

part_text=MIMEText(text, 'plain')

msg.attach(part_text)

mail=smtplib.SMTP_SSL(server)
mail.login(sms_from, password)
mail.sendmail(sms_from,sms_to,msg.as_string())
mail.quit()
```

ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 19, in <module>
part_text=MIMEText(text, 'plain')

line 34, in __init__
_text.encode('us-ascii')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас сообщение об ошибке дает четкое понимание что происходит:

`part_text=MIMEText(text, 'plain')` вот в этой строчке что то не верно.

Вы передаете переменную `text`, которая имеет тип данных `tuple`. О чем вам и сообщает второе предложение в сообщении об ошибке. Что при инициализации объекта класса, `tuple` объект не имеет атрибута `encode`.

По моим предположениям там должна быть строка. Теперь идем в [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.mime.html) и находим там вот это:

```py
class email.mime.text.MIMEText(_text, _subtype='plain', _charset=None, *, policy=compat32)
Module: email.mime.text
```

И в описании класса находим `_text is the string for the payload.` Предположения подтвердились.

Исправляем:

```py
text= 'здравствуйте, ' + name
```

Теперь должно все заработать